# backing up/copying mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a DB which is a live one, what I'm looking to do, is to make a copy.
I have access to MySQl via SSH and phpMyAdmin.
Is there a command where I can copy/backup the DB, in a single command/action, without using export/import?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a command that would take a dump of one database and then insert it into another DB using a single command:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppassword live_db | mysql -u username -ppassword backup_db
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD databaseName > SAVETOFILE.sql
```

see this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html for various options available.

you can do via PHPMyAdmin as well see here http://php.about.com/od/learnmysql/ss/mysql_backup_3.htm

> 1. Login to phpMyAdmin
> 2. Click on your database name
> 3. Click on the tab labeled EXPORT
> 4. Select all tables you want to backup (usually all)
> 5. Default settings usually work, just make sure SQL is checked
> 6. Check the SAVE FILE AS box
> 7. Hit GO

---

If you want to create DB that is a copy of above sqldump you need to do run the following command

```
 mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD < SAVEDFILE.sql
```

But, I feel you are looking for something like replication. In that case you need to set-up master-slave configuration where data gets replicated on slave. See this guide for replication

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Comment: Is there a way, where I can use phpmyadmin to copy the database? i.e. If I create a new db in phpmyadmin, I can simply copy the live db to it? I don't want to use export if i can

Comment: @terrid25 from your description, it looks like you're looking for replication -- a place where live DB gets copied without any intermediate files being created. You may look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Comment: I wasn't sure I needed to use replication. But I guess I can look into it